# For RSA, does $p^e=p$ and $q^e=q$ hold?

Tags: encryption, rsa

Is it true that $p^e\equiv p \pmod n$ and $q^e\equiv q \pmod n$ for RSA?

Here $n=p\cdot q$, $p$ and $q$ are different prime numbers as required by the RSA system.

I have to find four examples of $w$: $w^e\equiv w \pmod n$ that always hold. My candidates are $p,q,-p,-q$.

It works on examples but I can't prove it.

Comment: What you are asked to find is called a _fixed-point_ of the RSA encryption function.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it true that in RSA $p^e\equiv p \pmod n$ and $q^e\equiv q \pmod n$?

No, it is not always true (and, for realistic RSA modulii, it is rarely true).  To take an example, if we have $p = 11$, $q = 17$ and $e = 3$, we have $p^e \equiv 22 \not\equiv p$ and $q^e \equiv 51 \not\equiv q$

> (I have to find four examples of $w$: $w^e\equiv w \pmod n$. My candidates are $p,q,-p,-q$.)

Actually, there are always at least nine examples, however those four aren't it.  I'll give you three for free: 0, 1, and $n-1$, all you need is a fourth one...

Comment: @SEJPM: read assignment 6 closer; it is asking for the number of fixed points *relatively prime to* $n$; if we remove that arbitrary restriction, we get the HoAC answer...

Comment: More accurately, there are at least $(1+\gcd(e-1,p-1))(1+\gcd(e-1,q-1))$ fixed points for any modulus $n=pq$ and knowledge of a fourth fixed point is equivalent to factoring (apparently).

Answer (score 2):

Let $p\neq q$ be distinct primes, let $n:=p\cdot q$ and $ \mathbb N\ni e\geq1$. Let w.l.o.g. $p$ be the number to be encrypted. Further let $\theta:\mathbb Z_n\to\mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_q:x\mapsto (x\bmod p,x\bmod q)$ be the map defined by the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement). Note that $\theta$ is a ring isomorphism meaning it preserves addition and multiplication and also note that $\theta$ is a bijection.

Now we shall apply $\theta(p^e)=(p^e\bmod p,p^e\bmod q)=(0,p^e\bmod q)$. now because the inverse $c$ of a given chinese remainder map is determined by the equations
\begin{align}
0\equiv c&\pmod p\\
p^e\equiv c&\pmod q
\end{align}

with the constraint that $0\leq c<n$, we know that the encryption $c$ of $p$ must be of the form $kp$ for some $0\leq k<q$.

This assertion is supported by the counter-example to your conjecture which is $e=3,p=5,q=17$ yielding $40$ as the encryption. So it appears that we can't make a stronger assertion about the form of the output than the one above.